# How to get human readable (and terse!) output from describe-instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to figure out how to get very concise and human readable output from `aws ec2 describe-instances`. I realize I can do `aws ec2 describe-instances --output table` but it's still way too much. Ideally I'd want to see something that just shows the instance ID, the name tag that I've created, and its state. Very similar to what you see in the web console:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to combine your command with `query` parameter to get the right result:

For example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[0].Value,InstanceId,State.Name]' --output table

+------------------+-------------+----------+
|  RABBIT-SERVER-1 |  i-12345cc1 |  running |
|  RABBIT-SERVER-2 |  i-12345d74 |  running |
|  MANAGEMENT-SERV |  i-123457b2 |  stopped |
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This helped me figure out how to add other useful stuff to the query, e.g. `aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[0].Value,InstanceId,InstanceType,State.Name,NetworkInterfaces[0].Association.PublicIp]" --output table`